# RobotFramework: Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Input Text' Error Keyword 'Input Username' expected 1 arguments, got 0

Tags: selenium-ide, robotframework

Code:

```
Input Username
    [Arguments]    ${username}
    Input Text    login_username_id    ${username}
```

Error:- `Keyword 'Input Username' expected 1 arguments, got 0`
May i know why am i getting this error?

Comment: It would help if you could show the code that is calling your keyword, because that is where the error is located.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in self as the first argument in your method. Something like:

```
def input_username(self, arg1):
```

Comment: Simple, direct, and saved my day! + 1

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: your keyword `Input Username` expects exactly one argument, but the place where you are calling it is only providing one argument.